# Pop up text edit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup

I'm building a football formation web app which requires 11 divs to be draggable, droppable and swappable (I've managed this so far). I would also like to be able to click the div and have a pop-up which allows for the player name (and a backup player name) to be edited.

I'm struggling to find any jQuery plugins that are suitable. The closest I have found is x-editable but it doesn't seem to be supported and is quite tailored to an old version of bootstrap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle?

Comment: `var name = prompt("Player Name:");`

Comment: @MatthewBlewitt Here is the basic principle [https://jsfiddle.net/k6gLt48m/17/](https://jsfiddle.net/k6gLt48m/17/)

Comment: @AntonyArmstrong why not use Sortable?

Comment: @AntonyArmstrong where is the player name and backup name found / stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with very little explanation. In the future, please make sure to provide a more complete example of your current code. Also Ensure that you describe what you have tried.

This largely does what you're discussing. I would consider looking at Dialog, but this is a little more custom built.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u9xckmq6/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var box = $(".pitch");
  var mainCanvas = $(".main-canvas");

  function hidePopUp(event) {
    $t = $(event.target);
    if ($t.parents("div").attr("class") !== "pop-up") {
      return !$(event.target).closest(".pitch").length;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  box.draggable({
    containment: mainCanvas,
    helper: "clone",
    start: function() {
      $(this).css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $(".pitch").css("z-index", "0");
    },
    stop: function() {
      $(this).css({
        opacity: 1
      });
    }
  });

  box.droppable({
    accept: box,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      var droppable = $(this);
      var dragPos = draggable.position();
      var dropPos = droppable.position();
      draggable.css({
        left: dropPos.left + "px",
        top: dropPos.top + "px",
        "z-index": 20
      });
      droppable.css("z-index", 10).animate({
        left: dragPos.left,
        top: dragPos.top
      });
    }
  });

  box.click(function(e) {
    var $self = $(this);
    var pslot = $self.data("player");
    var pname = $self.text().trim();
    $(".pop-up").data("player", pslot);
    $(".pop-up input").val(pname);
    $(".pop-up").position({
      my: "center top+10",
      at: "center bottom",
      of: $self,
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $(".arrow").remove();
        $("<div>")
          .addClass("arrow")
          .addClass((feedback.vertical == "top" ? "bottom" : "top"))
          .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
          .appendTo(this);
      }
    }).data("visible", true).show();
  });

  $(".pop-up button").button({
    icon: "ui-icon-check",
    showLabel: false
  });

  $(".pop-up form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pname = $("input", this).val();
    var pslot = $(this).parent().data("player");
    console.log("Saving", pname, pslot);
    $(".player" + pslot).html(pname);
    $(".pop-up").hide();
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (hidePopUp(e)) {
      $(".pop-up").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

The Arrow is stripped from http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style and modified a little. Changes are only saved when <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the `<button>` is pressed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Apologies for the lack of detail in my original post, it's my first and I underestimated how much was required!

Comment: If it helped I hope you will upvote it. If it answered your question I hope you'll mark it as the answer.